# Issues compiling Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, .net, coffeescript

I have a really simple coffescript class:

```
class Bar
   foo: ->
      console.log('bar')
```

Which when compiled using coffee -c bar.coffee is being compiled into

```
(function() {
  class(Bar({
    foo: function() {
      return console.log('bar');
    }
  }));
}).call(this);
```

If it makes any difference I'm in Windows and the exact same coffeescript compiles correctly using [SassAndCoffee](https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/SassAndCoffee). I have tried a number of different compilers (Node.exe + latest coffescript source, [Coffee.exe](https://github.com/alisey/CoffeeScript-Compiler-for-Windows), etc) but all are showing the same behaviour. Has anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: Sadly, no.  Compiles fine for me (coffeescript v 1.1.1), sorry.  I also ran the coffee.exe you linked to under Windows XP and it worked fine.  Are you sure you don't have a spaces-vs-tabs issue in your original file?

Comment: As Elf suggests, the only way I can see this issue arising is if your file has some very unusual whitespace in it. I'd try retyping the code in a different editor.

Comment: @Trevor - I tried all manner of weird tabs-vs-spaces things in the source sample and Coffee still accepted it fine and produced the same results every time.  Under linux, tho.

Comment: Check _bar.coffee_'s charset and BOM. What does `(class)` compile to?

Comment: I converted to UTF 8 without BOM in notepad++ which seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help! Does any of you want to answer below so you get the points?

Comment: Sure.  And, dammit, I ought to be able to give you a 'good citizen' reputation award for suggesting it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James, check and see if you have unusual whitespace in your code that's confusing Coffeescript's parser.  Since Coffeescript is a whitespace-delimited language (usually), a tabs-vs-spaces mistake might be the source of your error.